# Server not selected on VS code

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to connect mssql on visual studio code but can not. i got the following notifications:
**server not selected**
and this error message**mssql: Error: Unable to connect using the connection information provided. Retry profile creation?**.

Comment: can you share some (obfuscated) details?

Comment: @user1443098 I got this detail error message also:Error connecting to server "localhost:1433". Details: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Is SQL Server installed and running on your computer (localhost)? (check the running services)  What do you put in the connection information when you try to connect?  That is, when you were prompted for the sql server instance, what did you specify? e.g. I can get this error if I try to connect to a non-existent SQL server instance on my local machine

Comment: I had the same error, and Named Pipes was disabled.  Check this: https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/infinityinstaller/content/installermaster/tkenablenamedpipesandtcpipconnections.htm